# Ghost running on docker container does not respond to http requests from other container

Tags: nginx, docker, wget, ghost-blog

I am setting up a ghost blog instance inside a docker container. I bound the ghost server to host 0.0.0.0 and exposed the port on which it's listening (port 2368). If I run wget to the ghost container's ip and ghost's port from the outside, the index is fetched, but if I run wget from within another container using the exact same ip and port, wget reports

```
--2014-03-20 02:58:27--  http://172.17.0.5:2368/
Connecting to 172.17.0.5:2368... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

and hangs indefinitely. I want to be able to connect to the ghost instance from within another container because I'll be using the second container as a reverse proxy with nginx (I'm using wget because I want to test connectivity since my attempts with nginx resulted in Gateway Timeouts). Is this expected or does ghost require additional configuration to serve content to another docker container?

**Update**

I forgot to mention that the 'reverse proxy to be' container is linked to the ghost instance container.

Answer (score 1):

If the nginx setup is going to be for the life of your ghost blog then you might want to use the docker feature of linking containers.

http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_links_names/